# Adding binary header

Tags: python-3.x

I have a binary data file I would like to append a header to using python. Below is the code I have to create the header but I am unsure on how to add it to the test.dat file.

```
import struct
import os
from struct import *

date = 20151027
version = 1
datatype = str.encode('P')
indextype = str.encode('I')
recct = int(os.path.getsize("H:\\test\\test.dat")/16)
delim = str.encode(' ')
filler = str.encode(' ')
delta = 'F'

pdate = pack('l', date)
pversion = pack('h', version)
pdatatype = pack('>s', datatype)
pindextype = pack('>s', indextype)
precct = pack('l', recct)
pdelim = pack('s', delim)
pfiller = pack('<2s', filler)

header = pdate+pversion+pdatatype+pindextype+precct,pdelim,pfiller
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the file in, then write the file out with the header.  Be sure to use binary mode:

```
with open(r'H:\test\test.dat','rb') as f:
    data = f.read()
with open(r'H:\test\test.dat','wb') as f:
    f.write(header + data)
```

Also, you can `pack` in one statement:

```
header = struct.pack('lhssls2s',date,version,datatype,indextype,recct,delim,filler)
```

`str.encode('P')` is an odd way of saying `'P'.encode()` or just `b'P'`.

Comment: It's the same as the previous one, except for write vs. read.  Check that you typed it correctly.